# What part of integer bit-representation is part of The Standard?

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

How much can one assume about integers' representation in memory?

How portable way of slicing and splicing integers together are bit-wise operations?

Comment: None - C/C++ does not deal with hardware/system representations of fundamental types.

Comment: @DieterLücking: That's not entirely true. First off, there is no "C/C++" language; the two languages are quite similar, but not identical. The [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (that's the N1570 draft) discusses representations of integer types in section 6.2.6.2, and goes into a fair amount of detail. There's probably something similar in the C++ standard, but I haven't checked.

Comment: @Cyber: This is not a duplicate of that question, which only discusses the *sizes* of integer types, not their representations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) discusses the representations of integer types in section 6.2.6.2.

It specifies a binary representation for integer types. For unsigned types, the bits are divided into *value bits* and *padding bits*. Padding bits do not contribute to the value; there needn't be any padding bits. For signed types, there is a single sign bit. Signed types may be represented using either *sign and magnitude*, *two's complement*, or *one's complement* (two's complement is nearly universal for modern systems).

The ordering of the bits, and the presence and number of padding bits, are implementation-defined. (Most modern implementations do not have padding bits).

The concept of padding bits, and the restriction to the three canonical representations, were introduced in C99.

The bitwise operators (`<<`, `>>`, `&`, et al) are defined in terms of the bits making up the representation of the values of the operands, but the requirements on the representations are specific enough that this is unambiguous for most cases. The description of the `<<` and `>>` shift operators specifically says that, for example, the result of `E1 << E2` is `E1` × `2`<sup>`E2`</sup>; see section 6.5.7 of the cited N1570 draft.

The C++ standard has a non-normative note that says it permits 2’s complement, 1’s complement and signed magnitude representations for integral types, but there doesn't seem to be an explicit statement that no other representations are permitted. It does require that "The representations of integral types shall define values by use of a pure binary numeration system.". You can see the gory details in the [N4296 working draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) of the C++ standard (or in any other draft, or in the standard itself if you have a copy).