# What does i+=(i&-i) do? Is it portable?

Tags: c++, integer, bit-manipulation

Let `i` be a signed integer type. Consider

```
i += (i&-i);
i -= (i&-i);
```

where initially `i>0`.

1. What do these do? Is there an equivalent code using arithmetic only?
2. Is this dependent on a specific bit representation of negative integers?

*Source: setter's code of an online coding puzzle (w/o any explanation/comments).*

Comment: Interesting aside, `i & -i` forms a fractal pattern for contiguous values of `i`, for example: `0 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 8 1 4 1 2 1 16 1 2 1 4 ...`

Comment: Hope [this](https://www.hackerearth.com/practice/data-structures/advanced-data-structures/fenwick-binary-indexed-trees/tutorial/) article will help you. Nicely explained there.

Comment: @BishalGautam This link doesn't work properly (if you're not logged into hackerrank I presume).

Comment: @Walter, it is working fine for me even without login in. The article is "Fenwick (Binary Indexed) Trees tutorial in HackerEarth". This can also be accessed through Code Monk App (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hackerearth.codemonk&hl=en) .

Comment: @BishalGautam This must be because you have an account. No chance here.

Comment: @Walter I don't have an account and i can view it.

Comment: @Walter It's accessible publically. Something blocks on your side. E.g. disabled cookies :P

Comment: @Walter, I don't know why you are facing problem. But, seems like either its problem in your browser or content may be restricted in your region. You may try alternative ways to access article.

Comment: Oh yes..... what exactly is "arithmetic only"? Which operators on what operand types are allowed?

Comment: **Possible duplicate**: [c++ - meaning of (number) & (-number) - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818978/meaning-of-number-number). As this question is broader (in the sense that "it applies for more signed representation"), somebody may want to close it the reverse way.

Comment: @user202729 What I really wanted are operations that don't rely for the correctness of the expression on the integer bit representation. I think if only `+ - / * % >> <<` but not `& | ^` are used, this would be the case. However, I now know that `i&=i-1` is equivalent to `i-=(i^-i)` *independently of the bit representation*. Thus this part of my question was not very well expressed. Ideally all this should work for unsigned (it does).

Comment: ... why is `>>` and `<<` "no bitwise manipulation"?

Comment: Must they be applied on signed number, or unsigned can work as well?

Comment: Are you sure that the code uses *signed* integers? Because then it’s a toss-up, whereas the code is well-defined and specified by the standard if `i` is unsigned.

Comment: @KonradRudolph well, initially `i>0`, so there is no difference between signed & unsigned.

Comment: @Walter Yes there **is** a difference. Especially on 1's complement machines.

Comment: @Walter That is incorrect. Arithmetic is defined differently for signed and unsigned types in C++ and, as mentioned, the code is *well-defined* for unsigned integers (i.e. it is guaranteed to work) but it is *implementation defined* for signed integers (i.e. it may or may not work).

Comment: @user202729 Yes.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Are you saying that `i += (i&-i)` is guaranteed to work if `i` is an unsigned type? In other words, `-i` will always map to the two's complement of `i` for unsigned, no matter how signed types are represented?

Comment: In unsigned, all arithmetic operators are done modulo one plus the largest representable value.

Comment: @Walter Yes, exactly.

Comment: [Finally found the answer that states that bitwise operation on unsigned is well-defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28591285).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `i` has unsigned type, the expressions are completely portable and well-defined.

If `i` has signed type, it's not portable, since `&` is defined in terms of representations but unary `-`, `+=`, and `-=` are defined in terms of values. If the [next version of the C++ standard mandates twos complement](https://twitter.com/jfbastien/status/989242576598327296), though, it will become portable, and will do the same thing as in the unsigned case.

In the unsigned case (and the twos complement case), it's easy to confirm that `i&-i` is a power of two (has only one bit nonzero), and has the same value as the lowest-place bit of `i` (which is also the lowest-place bit of `-i`). Therefore:

- `i -= i&-i;` clears the lowest-set bit of `i`.
- `i += i&-i;` increments (clearing, but with carry to higher bits) the lowest-set bit of `i`.

For unsigned types there is never overflow for either expression. For signed types, `i -= i&-i` overflows taking `-i` when `i` initially has the minimum value of the type, and `i += i&-i` overflows in the `+=` when `i` initially has the max value of the type.

Answer (score 11):

The expression `i & -i` is based on [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) being used to represent negative integers. Simply put, it returns a value `k` where each bit except the least significant **non-zero** bit of `i` is set to `0`, but that particular bit keeps its own value. (i.e. `1`)

As long as the expression you provided executes in a system where [Two's Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) is being used to represent negative integers, it would be portable. So, the answer to your second question would be that the expression *is* dependent on the representation of negative integers.

To answer your first question, since arithmetic expressions are dependent on the data types and their representations, I do not think that there is a solely arithmetic expression that would be equivalent to the expression `i & -i`. In essence, the code below would be equivalent in functionality to that expression. (assuming that `i` is of type `int`) Notice, though, that I had to make use of a loop to produce the same functionality, and not just arithmetics.

```
int tmp = 0, k = 0;
while(tmp < 32)
{
    if(i & (1 << tmp))
    {
        k = i & (1 << tmp);
        break;
    }
    tmp++;
}
i += k;
```

Comment: I think you should initialize `k` with zero in your code example. Otherwise - if `i==0` - the `if` never triggers and you add a random number to `i`.

Comment: @ClaasBontus The question assumes that `i > 0`, but I went ahead and updated my code to handle that case as well.

Comment: This has nothing to do with twos complement unless `i` has signed type.

Comment: @R.. Then it is great that the question assumes that `i` has a signed type.

Comment: Uhg, sorry, somehow I missed that entirely.

Answer (score 10):

On a Two's Complement architecture, with 4 bits signed integers:

```
|  i |  bin | comp | -i | i&-i | dec |
+----+------+------+----+------+-----+
|  0 | 0000 | 0000 | -0 | 0000 |   0 |
|  1 | 0001 | 1111 | -1 | 0001 |   1 |
|  2 | 0010 | 1110 | -2 | 0010 |   2 |
|  3 | 0011 | 1101 | -3 | 0001 |   1 |
|  4 | 0100 | 1100 | -4 | 0100 |   4 |
|  5 | 0101 | 1011 | -5 | 0001 |   1 |
|  6 | 0110 | 1010 | -6 | 0010 |   2 |
|  7 | 0111 | 1001 | -7 | 0001 |   1 |
| -8 | 1000 | 1000 | -8 | 1000 |   8 |
| -7 | 1001 | 0111 |  7 | 0001 |   1 |
| -6 | 1010 | 0110 |  6 | 0010 |   2 |
| -5 | 1011 | 0101 |  5 | 0001 |   1 |
| -4 | 1100 | 0100 |  4 | 0100 |   4 |
| -3 | 1101 | 0011 |  3 | 0001 |   1 |
| -2 | 1110 | 0010 |  2 | 0010 |   2 |
| -1 | 1111 | 0001 |  1 | 0001 |   1 |
```

Remarks:

1. You can conjecture that `i&-i` only has one bit set (it's a power of 2) and it matches the least significant bit set of `i`.
2. `i + (i&-i)` has the interesting property to be one bit closer to the next power of two.
3. `i += (i&-i)` sets the least significant unset bit of `i`.

So, doing `i += (i&-i);` will eventually make you jump to the next power of two:

```
| i | i&-i | sum |     | i | i&-i | sum |
+---+------+-----+     +---+------+-----+
| 1 |    1 |   2 |     | 5 |    1 |   6 |
| 2 |    2 |   4 |     | 6 |    2 |  -8 |
| 4 |    4 |  -8 |     |-8 |   -8 |  UB |
|-8 |   -8 |  UB |

| i | i&-i | sum |     | i | i&-i | sum |
+---+------+-----+     +---+------+-----+
| 3 |    1 |   4 |     | 7 |    1 |  -8 |
| 4 |    4 |  -8 |     |-8 |   -8 |  UB |
|-8 |   -8 |  UB |
```

UB: overflow of signed integer exhibits undefined behavior.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what I researched prompted by other answers. The bit manipulations

```
i -= (i&-i);   // strips off the LSB (least-significant bit)
i += (i&-i);   // adds the LSB
```

are used, predominantly, in traversing a [Fenwick tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree). In particular, `i&-i` gives the LSB if signed integers are represented via [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement). As already [pointed out by Peter Fenwick](http://camlunity.ru/swap/Library/Computer%20Science/Algorithms%20and%20Data%20Structures/fenwick-tree.pdf) in his original proposal, this is not portable to other signed integer representations. However,

```
i &= i-1;      // strips off the LSB
```

is (it also works with [one's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ones%27_complement) and [signed magnitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations) representations) and has one fewer operations.

However there appears to be no simple portable alternative for adding the LSB.

Comment: @DavidFoerster because `i &= ~1` and `i &= i - 1` are very different, one is to get the least significant bit, one is to get the least significant **set** bit

Comment: [Here is a visual representation of Fenwick tree](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35887846/995714)

Comment: @DavidFoerster I know. A lot of word usage on this question is incorrect

Comment: The portable way to add the bit is `i += (i & -(unsigned)i)`. To obfuscate it just use [`i & (i ^ (i - 1))`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24772669/995714)

Comment: @phuclv with the figures stolen from Fenwicks original publication :-)

Answer (score 3):

`i & -i` is the easiest way to get the least significant bit (LSB) for an integer `i`.
You can read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering#Least_significant_bit.).
A1: You can read more about 'Mathematical Equivalents' [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#Mathematical_equivalents).
A2: If the negative integer representation is not the usual standard form (i.e. weird big integers), then `i & -i` might not be LSB.

Comment: There is no such thing as a standard form for bit-representing negative integers. Yes, almost all hardware these days uses two's complement, but AFAIK, the language standard does not require that.

Comment: Yes, maybe I used wrong words. If the representation is not in the two's complement, the output would be different.

Comment: @DavidFoerster is right, it's the way to get the rightmost set bit (in the non-negative bit pattern). And the cross-platform way to do that regardless of signed type representation is `i & -(unsigned)i` because unsigned maths are reduced modulo 2^n

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to think of it is in terms of the mathematical equivalence:

```
-i == (~i + 1)
```

So `-i` inverts the bits of the value and then adds `1`. The significance of this is that all the lower `0` bits of `i` are turned into `1`s by the `~i` operation, so adding `1` to the value causes all those low `1` bits to flip to `0` whilst carrying the `1` upwards until it lands in a `0` bit, which will just happen to be the same position as the lowest `1` bit in `i`.

Here's an example for the number 6 (0110 in binary):

```
i = 0110
~i == 1001
(~i + 1) == 1010
i & (~i + 1) == 0010
```

You may need to do each operation manually a few times before you realise the patterns in the bits.

Here's two more examples:

```
i = 1000
~i == 0111
(~i + 1) == 1000
i & (~i + 1) == 1000

i = 1100
~i == 0011
(~i + 1) == 0100
i & (~i + 1) == 0100
```

See how the `+ 1` causes a sort of 'bit cascade' carrying the one up to the first open `0` bit?

---

So if `(i & -i)` is a means of extracting the lowest `1` bit, then it follows that the use cases of `i += (i & -i)` and `i -= (i & -i)` are attempts to add and subtract the lowest 1 bit of a value.

Subtracting the lowest 1 bit of a value from itself serves as a means to zero out that bit.

Adding the lowest 1 bit of a value to itself doesn't appear to have any special purpose, it just does what it says on the tin.

---

It should be portable on any system using two's complement.